# Query/Filter Core Data Entities with common parent whom are not key value complient

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

Is there a way create a predicate query to filter child entities? I would like to be able to return a single result set with filtering applied to the children.

For example I have Shape. And Circle an Square are shapes and I want to do this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext * context = [self managedObjectContext];

Circle * c = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Circle" inManagedObjectContext:context];
c.radius = @(10);

Square * s = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Square" inManagedObjectContext:context];
s.width = @(100);
s.height = @(200);


NSFetchRequest * f= [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Shape"];
f.predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" radius = 10 OR hight = 200"];;
NSArray * results = [context executeFetchRequest:f error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",results);
```

This produces a key value exception to be called when the fetch request is executed because a square does not have a radius, and a circle does not have a height and width.

Comment: Have you tried it?  What happens when you try?  What error, if any, do you get?

Comment: this produced a key value error as radius is not a member of Square.

Comment: During the execution of the fetch request?

Comment: this, it was during the fetch request

Answer (score 2):

You can only achieve this by two ways - either add all possible properties to all entities (add `radius` to `Square` and `width`, `height` to `Circle`) or execute two fetch requests, one for circles and one for squares. I am for the second method.

```
NSFetchRequest * f = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Circle"];
f.predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" radius = 10"];
NSArray * results = [context executeFetchRequest:f error:nil];

if(results == nil) { results = @[]; }

f = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Square"];
f.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"height = 200"];

results = [results arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[context executeFetchRequest:f error:nil]];
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go with denormalizing the `Shape` entity:

Include all properties (which is the internal implementation of CoreData in any case [for a SQLite store]) in the `Shape` entity and only create implementations (@dynamic) for specialised shapes (`Circle`, `Square`, ...).
You can limit this denormalization to only properties you need to search by.

**Notes:**

1. You might want to avoid setting a default value for the denormalized properties in the `Shape` entity, as the inheriting entities would still return value when using: `[object valueForKey:@"somepropertynamefromspecializedclass"];`. This way they would return `nil` for such keys.
2. You might also want to add a `shapeType` property to your `Shape` entity so you might be able to limit your search for only specific types of `Shape`s

This way you only need a single fetch to get the objects you want and track them with a single FRC.

Example:

`Shape`: [abstract entity] (shapeType,name,radius,width,height): generate implementation for this entity (Shape.h and Shape.m) but remove the implementation for properties that were denormalized (radius,width,height)
so your `Shape` .h file looks like:

```
@interface Shape : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * shapeType;
//radius ,width and height were removed (REMEMBER TO REMOVE THEM FROM YOUR .M FILE AS WELL)
@end
```

`Shape` .m file:

```
@implementation Shape
@dynamic name;
@dynamic shapeType;
@end
```

`Circle`: [inherit from `Shape`] ()

`Circle` .h file:

```
@interface Circle : Shape
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSNumber* radius;
@end
```

`Circle` .m file:

```
@implementation Circle
@dynamic radius;
@end
```

`Rectangle`: [inherit from `Shape`] ()
implemented very similarly to `Circle`

and now somewhere in your code you can do:

```
Circle* c = (Circle*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Circle" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
c.name = @"circle";
c.shapeType = @"c";
c.radius = @(100);

Rectangle* rect = (Rectangle*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Rectangle" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
rect.name = @"rectangle";
rect.shapeType = @"r";
rect.width = @(150);
rect.height = @(200);

[self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
[self.managedObjectContext reset];

NSFetchRequest* r = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Shape"];
r.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"width > %@ OR radius > %@",@(100),@(90)];
NSArray* res = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:r error:nil];
```